# Restrict a particular alphabet combination in a field by validation

Tags: apex, custom-field, validation, validation-rule

Can I restrict ' PO Box' , ' P.O. Box' or these values alongwith hyphen or so from being entered in a particular text field on a custom field on Account?

Comment: Do you want to validate against literal values? In that case you could just use a combination of multiple BEGINS(customfield__c,'PO BOX'). Or should there be some additional logic in the validation?

Comment: I have to create a validation logic that will restrict user from entering those values on say a custom field AddressLine__c on Account.

Comment: They might enter ' Park Street PO Box22 ' , that also we need to restrict.

Comment: You can create a validation rule using REGEX() method to identify this pattern and block this!

Comment: I am trying that but getting confused. How to find regex formulas?

Comment: There's extensive documentation on Regex online. There's also a test fiddle where you can experiment: http://refiddle.com/#play

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK You can try with my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a validation rule using REGEX() method to identify this pattern and block this!
Please use the following regex for your scenario:

```
([P|p])\S?[\.| \r|]?([O|o])\S? ([B|b O|o X|x])\w+
```

This is working for the following matches

```
PO Box
P.O. Box 
P O Box
PO BOX
po box
P.O box
PO. box
```

Comment: So this will be the error formula?                                                                                        REGEX(Name,"([P|p])\S?[\.| \r|]?([O|o])\S? ([B|b O|o X|x])\w+")

Comment: This formula still gives error

Comment: What is the error? You can use this site to construct regex: http://www.regexr.com/ place my formula here and test your values. Matches will be highlighted

Comment: It is just showing syntax error in error formula criteria in validation rule

Answer (score 0):

Woudn't some javaScript fix the issue?

something like:

```
var edit = document.getElementById("{!$Component.ComponentId}");
document.edit.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = edit.value;
    var regx = /some regex/;
    if (text.match(regx) !== null) {
        // Some validation action
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need that as a formula in a validation rule.:(

Answer (score -1):

you can query the field brfore inserting to field  and use like in it but in this case you have to hard code  the combination of alphabets and decide what can be done if validation is true or false